# fullpage.js seems to loaded twice my page

Tags: symfony, fullpage.js

i'm using symfony 2.3 with bootstrap and [FullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) .

When i load my page, it seems to be loaded twice...

So my width slides in my section is wrong, and the code created is wrong too.

```
<div class="section active" id="section_admin" data-anchor="admin"">
   <div class="slides">
        <div class="slidesContainer" style="width: 300%;">
           <div class="slides">
              <div class="slidesContainer" style="width: 300%;">
                 <div class="slide active" data-anchor="slide1" style="width:
```

With the call plugin, my console log return two 'toto', if i remove the plugin my console log return one 'toto'.

Where I am  wrong ?

```
                <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/app_dev.php/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tcs.js"></script>


                <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/ivoryckeditor/ckeditor.js" ></script>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="/jQuery-File-Upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js" ></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/jQuery-File-Upload/js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js" ></script>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="/jQuery-File-Upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/select2.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/moment.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/daterangepicker.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dataDays.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dataDaysEnh.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dataHours.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.fn.gantt.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.myAlert.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>






                <!-- wysihtml5 parser rules -->
                <script type="text/javascript"src="/js/wysihtml5/parser_rules/advanced.js"></script>
                <!-- Library -->
                <script type="text/javascript"src="/js/wysihtml5/dist/wysihtml5-0.3.0.min.js"></script>
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />


                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css" type="text/css"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.ibutton.css" type="text/css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" type="text/css" />


                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/select2.css" type="text/css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/wysihtml5.css" type="text/css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/gantt.css" type="text/css" />

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/datepicker.css" type="text/css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/fullcalendar.css" type="text/css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css" type="text/css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/daterangepicker-bs3.css" type="text/css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.fullPage.css" type="text/css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.dataTables.css" type="text/css" />


                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/surcharge.css" type="text/css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/surcharge-dataTable.css" type="text/css" />


                </head>

        <body>


        <div  class="section" id="section_projet">

            <div id="myProject" class="col-lg-12">

            <div class="row">
                <div id="js-sidebar-projet" class="wrap col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-2" >
                <a href="/app_dev.php/todo/projet/add" class="visible-xs col-xs-12 btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <i class="icon-cogs"></i>
    <span>Nouveau projet</span>
    </a>
    <div class="sidebar bg-lighter">
    <div class="sub-sidebar" style=" border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF">
        <a  href="/app_dev.php/todo/projet/" >
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-9 col-md-8 col-lg-9"><span>Mes Projets</span></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><i class="icon-cogs"></i></div>
        </a>
    </div>
            <div class="sub-sidebar">
            <a  href="#"  onclick="loadOneProjet(1,8,event)" >
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                <span class="visible-xs">Dev</span>
                <span class="visible-sm visible-lg">Dev</span>
                <span class="visible-md">Dev</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" style="color: #5cb85c;">
                <i class="icon-sign-blank"></i>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <a class="" href="/app_dev.php/todo/delete/projet/8"onclick="return confirm('Are u sure ?')">
                <i class="icon-trash"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="sub-sidebar">
            <a  href="#"  onclick="loadOneProjet(1,5,event)" >
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                <span class="visible-xs">Projet 2</span>
                <span class="visible-sm visible-lg">Projet 2</span>
                <span class="visible-md">Projet 2</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" style="color: #b85ca9;">
                <i class="icon-sign-blank"></i>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <a class="" href="/app_dev.php/todo/delete/projet/5"onclick="return confirm('Are u sure ?')">
                <i class="icon-trash"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>          </div>
                <div id="js-load-projet" class="wrap col-sm-10 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                <div id='calendar'class="bg-lighter" style="padding: 10px;"></div>


                </div>

            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div  class="section" id="section_tache">

            <div id="wrap" class=" col-lg-12" style="padding-top: 20px;">
            <div class="row" style="">
                <div class="wrap col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-2" >
                <div class="sidebar bg-lighter" >

        <div class="sub-sidebar active">
            <a  href="#"  onclick="loadAjaxTaches('getActiveTaches',1,2,event)" title="Mes taches">
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1 text-center">
                    <i class="icon-fixed-width icon-inbox" ></i>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10 hidden-sm col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                    <span>Mes taches</span>
                </div>  
            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="sub-sidebar ">
            <a  href="#"  onclick="loadAjaxTaches('getTodayTaches',1,2,event)" title="Aujourd'hui">
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1 text-center">
                    <i class="icon-fixed-width icon-calendar" ></i>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10 hidden-sm col-md-9 col-lg-9 ">
                    <span>Aujourd'hui</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-sidebar ">
            <a  href="#"  onclick="loadAjaxTaches('getRecentTaches',1,2,event)" title="Updated">
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1 text-center">
                    <i class="icon-fixed-width icon-refresh" ></i>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10 hidden-sm col-md-10 col-lg-9 ">
                    <span>Updated</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-sidebar ">
            <a  href="#"  onclick="loadAjaxTaches('getMyAssignedTaches',1,2,event)" title="Assignée">
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1 text-center">
                    <i class="icon-fixed-width icon-hand-right" ></i>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10 hidden-sm col-md-9 col-lg-9 ">
                    <span>Assignée</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-sidebar ">
            <a  href="#"  onclick="loadAjaxTaches('getSQLSharedTaches',1,2,event)" title="Partagée">
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1 text-center">
                    <i class="icon-fixed-width icon-share" ></i>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10 hidden-sm col-md-9 col-lg-9 ">
                    <span>Partagée</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-sidebar">
            <a  href="#"  onclick="loadAjaxTaches('getUserlessTaches',1,2,event)" title="Orpheline">
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1 text-center">
                    <i class="icon-fixed-width icon-frown" ></i>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-10 hidden-sm col-md-9 col-lg-9 ">
                    <span>Orpheline</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
            </div>
                <div id="contenu" class="wrap col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-7 col-lg-8">
                    <table id="dataTable" class="table table-tache" >



    </table>


    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalImportance" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Priorité</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <a class=" js-modal-choice  icon-3x color-primary" data-dismiss="modal" data-value="1" data-color="color-primary">
                    <i class="icon-warning-sign"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="js-modal-choice  icon-3x color-warning" data-dismiss="modal" data-value="2" data-color="color-warning">
                    <i class="icon-warning-sign"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class=" js-modal-choice  icon-3x color-danger" data-dismiss="modal" data-value="3" data-color="color-danger">
                    <i class="icon-warning-sign"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Choisissez ...</h4>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>

    jQuery('.js-modal-choice').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        rate_id = jQuery(e.currentTarget).attr('data-value');
        tache_id = myGlobalVar.attr('data-tache');
        color = jQuery(e.currentTarget).attr('data-color');
        console.log(rate_id);

        path = Routing.generate('tcs_todo_ajax_edit_importance');

        jQuery.ajax({  
            type: "POST",
            url: path,
            data: "tache_id="+tache_id+"&importance_id="+rate_id,
            cache: false,
            success: function(msg) {

                myGlobalVar.attr('class','js-modal  '+color);


            },          
            error: function(msg) { 
                console.log( 'r&té');
            }        
        });
    });

    </script><script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {


    $('#dataTable').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "oLanguage":    {   "sSearch": "" ,
                    "oPaginate": {
                       "sFirst": "<i class='icon-fast-backward visible-xs' title='Début'></i><div class='hidden-xs'> Début</div>",
                       "sLast": "<i class='icon-fast-forward visible-xs' title='Fin'></i><div class='hidden-xs'> Fin</div>",
                       "sNext": "<i class='icon-forward visible-xs' title='Suivant'></i><div class='hidden-xs'> Suiv.</div>",
                       "sPrevious": "<i class='icon-backward visible-xs' title='Précedent'></i><div class='hidden-xs'> Préc.</div>",
                    }
                },
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
            //jQuery('tr').removeClass('odd');
            //jQuery('tr').removeClass('even');
            jQuery('#dataTable_filter').find('input').addClass('form-control input-sm');
            jQuery('#dataTable_filter').find('input').attr('placeholder','Recherche');
        },
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
            //dont apply odd even class, when warning class is present
            if (jQuery(nRow).hasClass('alert-warning')){
            jQuery(nRow).removeClass('odd');
            jQuery(nRow).removeClass('even');
            }


        }

        });    

    });   

     /********************************
     *      FONCTION DE RATING
     *******************************/

    jQuery('a.js-modal').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        myGlobalVar = jQuery(e.currentTarget);
        //console.log(jQuery(e.currentTarget));

    });
     /********************************
    *      PROGRESSION
    *******************************/
    $(".dial").knob({
        'height':48,
        'width': 48,
        'inline':false,
        'inputColor' :'#5cb85c',
        'fgColor':'#5cb85c',
        'bgColor':'#dff0d8',
        'thickness': '.1',

        'draw': function(){
            var hexa =  colored(this.cv);
            this.o.fgColor = hexa;
            this.$.css('color' ,hexa);
            $(this.i).val(this.cv + '%');
            if(this.$.data('skin') == 'tron') {

                var a = this.angle(this.cv)  // Angle
                    , sa = this.startAngle          // Previous start angle
                    , sat = this.startAngle         // Start angle
                    , ea                            // Previous end angle
                    , eat = sat + a                 // End angle
                    , r = 1;

                this.g.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;

                this.o.cursor
                    && (sat = eat - 0.3)
                    && (eat = eat + 0.3);

                if (this.o.displayPrevious) {
                    ea = this.startAngle + this.angle(this.v);
                    this.o.cursor
                    && (sa = ea - 0.3)
                    && (ea = ea + 0.3);
                    this.g.beginPath();
                    this.g.strokeStyle = this.pColor;
                    this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth, sa, ea, false);
                    this.g.stroke();
                }

                this.g.beginPath();
                this.g.strokeStyle = r ? this.o.fgColor : this.fgColor ;
                this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth, sat, eat, false);
                this.g.stroke();

                this.g.lineWidth = 2;
                this.g.beginPath();
                this.g.strokeStyle = this.o.fgColor;
                this.g.arc( this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth + 1 + this.lineWidth * 2 / 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                this.g.stroke();

                return false;
                }
            },

        'change' : function (v) {
        /****************************************************************
         * ICI J UTILISE UN TIMEOUT POUR DECLENCHER LA MAJ
         * LORSQU ON CHANGE LE NIVEAU AVEC LA SOURIS ON A PAS ENVIE
         * D AVOIR 5 APPELS AJAX POUR PASSER DE 30 A 35%
         * J ATTEND DONC QUE RIEN NE SE PASSE PENDANT 0.3 SEC
         ****************************************************************/
            if(typeof myTimeout != "undefined"){
                clearTimeout(myTimeout);
            }
            var hexa =  colored(this.cv);
            this.o.fgColor = hexa;
            this.$.css('color' ,hexa);
            tache_id = this.$.attr('data-id');
            myTimeout= setTimeout(function() {
                path = Routing.generate('tcs_todo_add_ajax_progression_tache');
                jQuery.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",
                    url: path,
                    data: "value="+v+"&tache_id="+tache_id,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(msg) {

                    },          
                    error: function(msg) { 
                        console.log( 'r&té');
                    }        
                });
            }, 400 );      
        },

    });
    </script>           </div>
                <div class="wrap col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <div class="sidebar bg-lighter">
                <div class="sub-sidebar">
                <a  href="#"  onclick="loadAjaxTaches('getPublicActiveTaches',16,2,event);" >
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 text-center">
                        <img class="avatar-xs"  src="/uploads/img/agra" ></img>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 hidden-sm col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                        <span class="visible-xs">agra</span>
                        <span class="visible-lg">agra</span>
                        <span class="visible-md">agra</span>
                    </div>


                </a>

            </div>

                <div class="sub-sidebar">
                <a  href="#"  onclick="loadAjaxTaches('getPublicActiveTaches',1,2,event);" >
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 text-center">
                        <img class="avatar-xs"  src="/uploads/img/blebris" ></img>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 hidden-sm col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                        <span class="visible-xs">blebris</span>
                        <span class="visible-lg">blebris</span>
                        <span class="visible-md">blebris</span>
                    </div>


                </a>

            </div>

                <div class="sub-sidebar">
                <a  href="#"  onclick="loadAjaxTaches('getPublicActiveTaches',44,2,event);" >
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 text-center">
                        <img class="avatar-xs"  src="/uploads/img/chapou" ></img>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 hidden-sm col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                        <span class="visible-xs">chapou</span>
                        <span class="visible-lg">chapou</span>
                        <span class="visible-md">chapou</span>
                    </div>


                </a>

            </div>

                <div class="sub-sidebar">
                <a  href="#"  onclick="loadAjaxTaches('getPublicActiveTaches',15,2,event);" >
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 text-center">
                        <img class="avatar-xs"  src="/uploads/img/clement" ></img>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 hidden-sm col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                        <span class="visible-xs">clement</span>
                        <span class="visible-lg">clement</span>
                        <span class="visible-md">clement</span>
                    </div>


                </a>

            </div>

                <div class="sub-sidebar">
                <a  href="#"  onclick="loadAjaxTaches('getPublicActiveTaches',46,2,event);" >
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 text-center">
                        <img class="avatar-xs"  src="/uploads/img/userless.jpg" ></img>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 hidden-sm col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                        <span class="visible-xs">le_nom_le_plus_long_du_monde_...</span>
                        <span class="visible-lg">le_nom_le_plus...</span>
                        <span class="visible-md">le_nom_le_...</span>
                    </div>


                </a>

            </div>

                <div class="sub-sidebar">
                <a  href="#"  onclick="loadAjaxTaches('getPublicActiveTaches',17,2,event);" >
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 text-center">
                        <img class="avatar-xs"  src="/uploads/img/redero" ></img>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 hidden-sm col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                        <span class="visible-xs">redero</span>
                        <span class="visible-lg">redero</span>
                        <span class="visible-md">redero</span>
                    </div>


                </a>

            </div>


    </div>



                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div  class="section" id="section_admin">
        <div class="slide active" data-anchor="slide1">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

            <div class="row">
                <div  class="wrap col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-2" >

                </div>
                <div class="wrap col-sm-10 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Groupes</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
            <li><a href="/app_dev.php/admin/group/list" ><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-list"></i> Voir les groupes</a></li>
            <li><a href="/app_dev.php/admin/group/new" ><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-plus"></i> Ajouter un groupe</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Utilisateurs</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
            <li><a href="/app_dev.php/profile/list" ><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-list"></i> Voir les utilisateurs</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">A.C.L.</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
            <li><a href="/app_dev.php/todo/view/menuAcl" ><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-refresh"></i> Donner des droits</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>  
                </div>

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

            <div class="row">
                <div  class="wrap col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-2" >

                </div>
                <div class="wrap col-sm-10 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Groupes</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
            <li><a href="/app_dev.php/admin/group/list" ><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-list"></i> Voir les groupes</a></li>
            <li><a href="/app_dev.php/admin/group/new" ><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-plus"></i> Ajouter un groupe</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Utilisateurs</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
            <li><a href="/app_dev.php/profile/list" ><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-list"></i> Voir les utilisateurs</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">A.C.L.</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
            <li><a href="/app_dev.php/todo/view/menuAcl" ><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-refresh"></i> Donner des droits</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>  
                </div>

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        </div>



        <script>


          jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            console.log('toto');


        $.fn.fullpage({
            verticalCentered: false,
            resize : true,
            slidesColor : ['transparent', 'transparent','transparent'],
            anchors:['projet','tache','admin'],
            scrollingSpeed: 700,
            easing: 'easeInQuart',
            menu: false,
            navigation: false,
            navigationPosition: 'right',
            navigationTooltips: ['firstSlide', 'secondSlide'],
            slidesNavigation: false,
            slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',
            loopBottom: false,
            loopTop: false,
            loopHorizontal: true,
            autoScrolling: true,
            scrollOverflow: false,
            css3: false,


            //events
            onLeave: function(index, direction){},
            afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){},
            afterRender: function(){},
            afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){},
            onSlideLeave: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction){}
        });



    });
        </script>


    <div id="sfwdt4d109a" class="sf-toolbar" style="display: none"></div><script>/*<![CDATA[*/    Sfjs = (function() {        "use strict";        var noop = function() {},            profilerStorageKey = 'sf2/profiler/',            request = function(url, onSuccess, onError, payload, options) {                var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');                options = options || {};                xhr.open(options.method || 'GET', url, true);                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');                xhr.onreadystatechange = function(state) {                    if (4 === xhr.readyState && 200 === xhr.status) {                        (onSuccess || noop)(xhr);                    } else if (4 === xhr.readyState && xhr.status != 200) {                        (onError || noop)(xhr);                    }                };                xhr.send(payload || '');            },            hasClass = function(el, klass) {                return el.className.match(new RegExp('\\b' + klass + '\\b'));            },            removeClass = function(el, klass) {                el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + klass + '\\b'), ' ');            },            addClass = function(el, klass) {                if (!hasClass(el, klass)) { el.className += " " + klass; }            },            getPreference = function(name) {                if (!window.localStorage) {                    return null;                }                return localStorage.getItem(profilerStorageKey + name);            },            setPreference = function(name, value) {                if (!window.localStorage) {                    return null;                }                localStorage.setItem(profilerStorageKey + name, value);            };        return {            hasClass: hasClass,            removeClass: removeClass,            addClass: addClass,            getPreference: getPreference,            setPreference: setPreference,            request: request,            load: function(selector, url, onSuccess, onError, options) {                var el = document.getElementById(selector);                if (el && el.getAttribute('data-sfurl') !== url) {                    request(                        url,                        function(xhr) {                            el.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;                            el.setAttribute('data-sfurl', url);                            removeClass(el, 'loading');                            (onSuccess || noop)(xhr, el);                        },                        function(xhr) { (onError || noop)(xhr, el); },                        options                    );                }                return this;            },            toggle: function(selector, elOn, elOff) {                var i,                    style,                    tmp = elOn.style.display,                    el = document.getElementById(selector);                elOn.style.display = elOff.style.display;                elOff.style.display = tmp;                if (el) {                    el.style.display = 'none' === tmp ? 'none' : 'block';                }                return this;            }        }    })();/*]]>*/</script><script>/*<![CDATA[*/    (function () {                Sfjs.load(            'sfwdt4d109a',            '/app_dev.php/_wdt/4d109a',            function(xhr, el) {                el.style.display = -1 !== xhr.responseText.indexOf('sf-toolbarreset') ? 'block' : 'none';                if (el.style.display == 'none') {                    return;                }                if (Sfjs.getPreference('toolbar/displayState') == 'none') {                    document.getElementById('sfToolbarMainContent-4d109a').style.display = 'none';                    document.getElementById('sfToolbarClearer-4d109a').style.display = 'none';                    document.getElementById('sfMiniToolbar-4d109a').style.display = 'block';                } else {                    document.getElementById('sfToolbarMainContent-4d109a').style.display = 'block';                    document.getElementById('sfToolbarClearer-4d109a').style.display = 'block';                    document.getElementById('sfMiniToolbar-4d109a').style.display = 'none';                }            },            function(xhr) {                if (xhr.status !== 0) {                    confirm('An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (' + xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText + ').\n\nDo you want to open the profiler?') && (window.location = '/app_dev.php/_profiler/4d109a');                }            }        );    })();/*]]>*/</script>
    </body>
```

Comment: It looks like you are adding the javascript file twice in your code. Could you add your URL so we can be sure of the cause?

Comment: Another cause could be that you are including the javascript file in the wrong place (not in the header of the site)

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't add an URL. My js file is including in the head section. I will edit my post with a copy of my html files.

Comment: That't not the HTML code, but the template code. Could you add the resulting HTML code?

Comment: Hope I paste the good HTML code! I copy the entire resulting body

Comment: Could you also add the headers and includes as well as the initialization of the plugin? The problem will probably be there. You must be initializating the plugin twice somewhere.

Comment: Ok done. I had to truncate a lot of <tr> in my <table> there was too many hmtl's lines in order to post

Comment: Could you show also the initialization of the plugin and where exactly is it located in your file? Also, the HTML you are using before the plugin modifies it.

Comment: ok done. I Think that i paste all infos. I remove the table content. Too many html'lines.

Comment: I would try it by adding the scrips as well as the scrips initializations at the header, where it is suppose to be. Right now fullpage initialization is at the bottom.

Comment: you're right !!!! No more problem !!!!  I have learned web dev with Symfony, and it's not a Symfony's method to put script initialization in the header....you teach me something !

Comment: arf, i forgot to thank you, thanks !

Comment: Well, that would be the proper semantic way to do it, but nowadays the recomendation is to do it like you were doing it. The problem is that right now the plugin operates over the body of the site instead over a wrapper and that's the why. 
I will try to fix it in future versions.

Comment: I would like to approve your answer, but I don't know how

Comment: I've added an answer below. Now you can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try it by adding the scrips as well as the scrips initializations at the header, where it is suppose to be. Right now fullpage initialization is at the bottom.

That would be the proper semantic way to do it, but nowadays the recommendation is to do it like you were doing it,at the bottom of the site, just before `</body>`. The problem is that right now the plugin operates over the body of the site instead over a wrapper and that's the why. I will try to fix it in future versions

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro , Could you more light on this what is the issue keeping inside body , because I see it running twice , once it exits , Are there some kind of listeners in fullpage.js ?

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad this answer is almost one year old. Right now (currently version 2.5.2) the problem does no exist anymore as fullPage.js requires a wrapper element to be initialized.

Comment: oh ok Thanks , Actually I was fixing an old site for mobile optimization , I was asking for my understanding.